# Qual alternativa para SQL_Latin1_General_CP1251_CS_AS em MySQL

Tags: mysql

Qual seria uma alternativa, em MySQL, para o COLLATION **SQL_Latin1_General_CP1251_CS_AS** para MySQL ou como posso remover a acentuação de uma string (ou para toda tabela ou coluna) utilizando comandos?

**Referência**:

https://www.dirceuresende.com/blog/como-remover-acentuacao-e-caracteres-especiais-de-uma-string-no-sql-server/