# Como converter valores de uma coluna para UPPERCASE

Tags: mysql

Utilizando comandos MySQL, seria possível converter todos valores de uma coluna para **UPPERCASE**?

Comment: Tipo [assim](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_func_ucase&ss=-1)?

Comment: SIM! é possível, quer fazer um update ou só comparar?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, exatamente.

Comment: Olá @rray, `update`.

Comment: O exemplo que coloquei faz apenas o select. Precisa mesmo alterar os dados do banco?

Comment: Sim, pois preciso comparar valores com outra tabela (que também irei passar para UPPER). @AndersonCarlosWoss

Comment: Você pode comparar usando `ucase` também.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652444/mysql-query-to-change-a-lower-case-to-upper-case

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, aproveitando o barco, consegue me auxiliar nessa questão? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/188477/qual-alternativa-para-sql-latin1-general-cp1251-cs-as-em-mysql

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo, obrigado pela referência.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Utilize o `UPPER()`

**SELECT**:

```
SELECT UPPER(campo) FROM `tabela`
```

**UPDATE**:

```
UPDATE tabela SET campo = UPPER(campo)
```